# toolchain.py AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, kivy, mobile-application

I'm trying to build my python kivy app for iOS. I've done all the steps in Kivy documentation for Creating a package for iOS. But when I want to run `$ python3 toolchain.py build python3 openssl kivy` in my terminal, this error occures:

```
  File "/.../kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 69, in shprint
    line_str = "\n".join(line.encode("ascii", "replace").decode().splitlines())
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to encode bytes. Instead, it makes more sense to *decode* them

Comment: well..the toolchain.py is installed from official kivy github and I don't have enough skills to securely modify it. I don't know what is it supposed to do.